# Does Ubuntu fiddle with my grub configuration at runtime?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, virtualbox, shutdown, hibernate

Usually (on my Debian server system) I am used to the fact that my grub configuration (=which entries appear, timeouts, default entries) will only be changed when I explicitely call `grub-install` (or install a new kernel).

I really want these parameters to be rock solid and under no circmstances changed automatically.

Is there anything in Ubuntu that changes grub configuration in any way (which entries are displayed, default entries, timeouts etc)? Especially related to hibernation modes, unclean shutdowns etc.?

If yes, how to prevent this? (I could try `chattr +i` but I'd like to to fix the actual issue)

**Reason:** I have a dual boot system (Win 10/Ubuntu). I configured grub to automatically boot Win 10 (by setting `GRUB_DEFAULT="Windows 10 (on /dev/sda1)"` in `/etc/default/grub`). I also access the same Ubuntu system in raw mode via VirtualBox on Win10 (I am aware of the risks and implications!). Now I face the following weird situation: When I save the state in VirtualBox (i.e. the Ubuntu system is not properly shutdown and in a way still running) and I reboot my computer, Windows 10 does *not* automatically start! Even worse, grub boots directly into Ubuntu, without even presenting a boot menu, giving a message or providing a timeout. Clearly this is very bad for my system that has never been properly shutdown in VirtualBox.

The only explanation I possibly have is that Ubuntu uses somewhere some script that alters the grub configuration, e.g. on a successful shutdown. However, I couldn't find anything. Also, it seems that at least /boot/grub/grub.cfg is untouched. So maybe there is more "runtime configuration" for grub?